# Jquery way to handle all ajax success  events in one place

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I  have a scenario where i need to handle all jquery success events in common place. because i want some delegate to be called after all the ajax success events.   I know we can use `$.ajaxComplete` or `$.ajaxSucess` for that.  But the problem is all my ajax calls have their own success handlers, so eventually $.ajaxSucess will be overwritten  .

And i know i can write a common method which i can put in all ajax success handlers. but i dont want to do that, i want to know a cleaner way.

is there a method handler already in jquery for that, or whats the best way to do it?

Comment: Just for clarity, you've spelt `$.ajaxSuccess` > `$.ajaxSucess` (with a missing c). And in `Jquery > 1.8` you're probably after  `$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
        alert('yeah boi!');
    });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`$.ajaxSuccess`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) method should work fine as seen in [this live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BVxY5/) and it doesn't conflict with existing ajax success handlers. It is executed after each of them:

```
$('#msg').ajaxSuccess(function(result) {
    alert('ajax succeeded');    
});
```

Comment: yeah, its weird its not working for me, i think i tried $.ajaxSucess not like $('#msg').ajaxSucess..

Comment: @Ramesh Vel, do you have a `<div id="msg"></div>` element in your DOM?

Comment: nope. i just tried as it like $.ajaxPrefilter().. i  still  not get it, whats the need of $('#msg'),

Answer (score 1):

```
$.when($.ajax("/page1.php"), $.ajax("/page2.php"))
  .then(mySuccessFunc, myFailureFunc);
```

Answer (score 1):

try in this way-

```
 $.when(// your all ajax call)
   .then(//delegate handler after ajax succes)
```

Answer (score 1):

`$.ajaxSuccess` is not overwritten by the local success handler, it is executed after the local one.

Answer (score 0):

Does :

```
$.ajaxStop(...)
```

Fixes your problem ?